# List<T> namespace could not be found - Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a List. I made sure I have the using statement
    using System.Collections.Generic;

I try using List in the code:

```
private List<Stock> stocks;
```

But I get the error:

> /mypathhere/StockBroker.cs(8,17): DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0246:
>   The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm programming in C# but I'm on a mac so I'm stuck using the Visual Studio Code application.

Comment: What's Stock? is the class accessable?

Comment: Yes, Stock is accessible.

Comment: Then try posting the whole StockBroker?? From the code, I see nothing special

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, what type of project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
"Systems.Collections": "version here"
```

to your project.json

Your framework field may look like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
       "dependencies": {
           "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
           "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
           "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
           "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
           "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
       }
   }
}
```

in your dependencies inside your project.json.

Comment: I tried that. Then I get a different error. Unable to locate Dependency System.Collections